# pthread_key_create() - When does the `destructor` function invoked?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I wrote a program to learn about thread-specific data on Linux (`Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu`), as following.

I try to print thread id in the destructor function passed to `pthread_key_create()`, but it seems only sub threads succeed to print, but the main thread didn't print that info.

**My question is:**

Does the destructor function called right before or after termination of a thread?

The reason why main thread didn't print the info, is it due to the main thread already destroyed?

**tsd_test.c**

```
// test of thread-specific data

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static pthread_once_t once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
static pthread_key_t tidKey;

static void destructor(void *buf) {
    unsigned long *_tid = buf;
    printf("destroy, tid: %lu\n", *_tid);
    free(buf);
}

static void createKey(void) {
    int s = pthread_key_create(&tidKey, destructor);
    if(s != 0) {
        printf("failed to create key\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void *store_tid() {
    int s;
    unsigned long *buf;

    // create key
    s = pthread_once(&once, createKey);
    if(s != 0) {
        printf("failed to create key\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    buf = pthread_getspecific(tidKey);
    if(buf == NULL) { // thread call this function for the first time,
        buf = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
        if(buf == NULL) {
            printf("failed to allocate memory, %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(-1);
        }
        // register buffer to specified key & current thread,
        s = pthread_setspecific(tidKey, buf);
        if(s != 0) {
            printf("failed to setspecific\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    // store tid to buffer,
    *buf = (unsigned long)pthread_self();
    printf("set tid to: %lu\n", *buf);

    return buf;
}

void tsd_test() {
    unsigned long *tidp_a = store_tid();
    printf("tid - before call another thread: %lu\n", *tidp_a);

    int s;
    pthread_t t2;
    s = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &store_tid, NULL);
    if(s != 0) {
        printf("failed to create thread\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    s = pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    if(s != 0) {
        printf("failed to join thread\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("tid - after call another thread: %lu\n", *tidp_a);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    tsd_test();
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile:**

```
gcc -pthread tsd_test.c
```

**Output:**

```
set tid to: 3076318976
tid - before call another thread: 3076318976
set tid to: 3076315968
destroy, tid: 3076315968
tid - after call another thread: 3076318976
```

You can see that only the sub thread print "destroy", while the main thread didn't.

Comment: OT: The signature required for a pthread function is `void*(*)(void*)`, so it should be `void *store_tid(void*)`. Compile with all warnings on (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc) to get notified of such issues.

Comment: @alk Got that, nice tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thread destructor is called when the thread exits, not when the process dies i.e. when `main()` exits, the entire process dies. So destructor will not be called on that.

Call  `pthread_exit(NULL);` either at the end of `main()` function or at the end `tst()` function (both are same really). Now, you will see the destructor being called.

Comment: I am wondering why `pthread_exit()` would make the difference ? Does it call the `destructor` before terminate the thread, or ... ?

Comment: Returning from a thread created by pthread_create() or calling `pthread_exit();` would implicitly call the destructor(s), if any. But returning or exiting from the main() doesn't do and it exits the whole process. POSIX on pthread_exit() says *After all cancellation cleanup handlers have been executed, if the thread has any thread-specific data, appropriate destructor functions will be called in an unspecified order.*

Comment: I saw that in the man page, I guess it would call `destructor` first, then trigger termination of the thread, no matter in main or sub threads.

Comment: No. Returning from main() thread (equivalent to calling `exit()`) is not same as returning from another thread (equivalent to calling `pthread_exit()`).

Comment: I mean, if use pthread_exit(), then pthread_exit() will call destructor first, before terminate the thread. I am not sure is that true, but it seems reasonable.

Comment: I guess `pthread_exit()` in the main thread gives another problem: destructors of global and static variables in the program don't get called. Those destructors may finalize some resources, e.g. flush buffers to files etc.